# Adding a timer to KeyListener

Tags: java, timer, keylistener

I extended a JFrame class and have my own model and JPanel extended classes as instance variables. I implemented KeyListener to my JFrame and it works with the arrow keys but my model moves extremely slow around the frame when I hold the keys down. My question is how do I attach the KeyListener methods to a timer or do something to make my model move faster when I hold the keys. Also if it is possible, how can the model move two directions at once, say left and up?

```
public class GameController extends JFrame implements KeyListener,ActionListener
{
    private GamePieces p;
    private GamePanel panel;
    private Timer timer;

    public GameController()
    {
        super("Balls");
        setSize(800, 600);
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        p = new GamePieces();
        panel = new GamePanel();

        p.addObserver(panel);

        c.add(panel);

        addKeyListener(this);

        panel.update(p, null);

        setResizable(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if (e.getSource() == timer)
        {
            p.checkEat();
            p.moveOthers();
            panel.update(p, null);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int s = 0;
    } 

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key==38)
        {
            p.up();
            panel.update(p, null);
        }
        else if (key==40)
        {
            p.down();
            panel.update(p, null);
        }
        else if (key==39)
        {
            p.right();
            panel.update(p, null);
        }
        else if (key==37)
        {
            p.left();
            panel.update(p, null);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int o = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        GameController a = new GameController();
        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Where did you ever guess what 37, 38, 39 and 40 mean? Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you can use `Key Bindings`.  `how can the model move two directions at once`The `KeyboardAnimation.java` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) shows how you can do this with Key Bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right way but it should be a little more sophisticated. Follow [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. You should have **model** which remembers where you panel should be - up(), down() methods only update this model. You should have **viewer** which shows panel at current position. panel.update() belongs to viewer. And then you should have **controller** which changes position (invoke these up and down, left and right) and invokes viewer when necessary - to show movement or just next frame.

Your KeyListener tells controller to move position in some intervals when key is pressed. And then it tells controller to stop doing so when key is released. See, all parts move smoothly and independently. Keylistener tells controller what to do, controller does - changes model and invokes viewer. Model does nothing - only holds data. Viewer does nothing only shows current data.

P.S. Don't forget thread safety since you will press multiple keys and they will invoke controller multiple times in the same thread.